# flutter web phone auth: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings')

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, web

I am trying to add firebase phone auth OTP verification in my flutter web app.
But getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'settings').
[image: Here is the screenshot of an error logged in console]

Please help in resolving this error.